# Subtract One row's value from another row in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to develop a sample program using Pig to analyse some log files. I want to analyze the running time of different jobs. When I read in the log file of the job, I get the start time and the end time of the job, like this:

```
(Wed,03/20/13,01:03:37,EDT)
(Wed,03/20/13,01:05:00,EDT)
```

Now, to calculate the elapsed time, I need to subtract these 2 timestamps, but since both timestamps are in the same bag, I'm not sure how to compare them. So I'm looking for an idea on how to do this. thanks!

Comment: Looks like this person is having the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15222459/1928660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a unique ID for the job that is in both log lines? Also is there something to indicate which event is start, and which is end?

If so, you could read the dataset twice, once for start events, once for end-events, and join the two together. Then you'll have one record with both events in it.

so:

```
A = FOREACH logline GENERATE id, type, timestamp;
START = FILTER A BY (type == 'start');

END = FILTER A  BY (type == 'end');

JOINED = JOIN START by ID, END by ID;

DIFF = FOREACH JOINED GENERATE (START.timestamp - END.timestamp); // or whatever;
```